# Is there a way to make Capybara do tests live in a browser?

Tags: rspec, capybara

I'd like to debug some of my tests and see what's actually happening. An easy way to do that would be to watch them play out in front of me. Is it possible to force Capybara to use an actual browser instance to run the tests visibly in front of you?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Of course it is possible! You can use **selenium** driver.

Add `selenium-webdriver` to your Gemfile. Then,  in your `spec_helper.rb` you'll have to set

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
```

When you'll launch your tests, a new **Firefox** window will open!

If you want **Chrome** to be opened, set the driver to `:selenium_chrome`

Remember to set `:js => true` in your test:

```
describe 'some test', :js => true do
 it "something" do
  .
  .
  .
 end
end
```

You can also learn more about drivers [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers)

Comment: anyway, I can suggest you to watch youtube.com/watch?v=BG_DDUD4M9E for more great tips!

Comment: many thanks for sharing the link, top draw. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Mine (on an existing code-base) was a similar (but slightly different) fix, remove `_headless` from

```ruby
driven_by :selenium_headless, using: :firefox
```

in `config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do` in the file *spec/rails_helper.rb*.